# openerp email Reminder on Lead: 1

Tags: email, openerp-7

I'm using the v7.0 of openerp.

A 3 days back, I started receiving many emails (Like 20 a day - even at times when the system is off) from my address email with a title object: "Reminder on Lead: 1 ".

Here is the body of the email:

```
Warning unprocessed incoming lead is more than 5 day old.
Name: Plan to Attend a Training
ID: 1
Description: Hello,
I am Jason from Le Club SARL.
I am intertested to attend a training organized in your company.
Can you send me the details ?
```

I am newly in openerp and even I did a google search but I haven't found a solution or to understand how can i stop this lot of received mail.

Hope someone could help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deactivated the cron job. Follow these steps:

1. Go to Setting => Technical => Scheduler => Scheduled Actions
2. Search out something like *Lead* or *Reminder on Lead*
3. If you found, than edit that record with `Active = False`
4. After that you will no longer get any emails from the system.